# wavesurfer js not working with foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to generate multiple wavesurfer audio waves using an foreach loop in php, but this is not working.I'm using the wavesurfer.js to generate a waveforms for audio clips, the problem I am enter code here having is that I have multiple audio files being pulled in a php while loop, and the javascript only seems to run for the first record returned..

```
<?php 
foreach ($aReleases as $aRelease) {
    $aTracks = explode(',',$aRelease['track_file']);
    foreach ($aTracks as $aTrack) {                                             
        $path = getConfig('mediaUrl').'uploads/'.$aTrack;  
        ?>  
        <div id="wave">    
            <div><?php echo ucfirst($aRelease['title']); ?></div>
            <canvas class='wave' data-path='<?php echo $path;?>'   data-id='<?php echo $id;?>' width='500' height='128'></canvas>
        </div>                                                
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ID of DOM element must be unique (`#wave` in your case).

Comment: It is unique but still not working.Please help me.

Comment: You tried `each` by `$('#wave)` selector. How you each by one unique element?

Comment: I don't know how to use this.

Comment: replace `<div id="wave">` with `<div class="js-wave">`, to example, and change js code to like `$('.js-wave').each.....`

Comment: And also i get error like (The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.)

Comment: you expect someone to do everything for you?

Comment: I Tried this but also getting error of (The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.)

Comment: No i want just help .

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/n5fmpnyy/1/ - I create example for you.

Comment: okay thanks let me try it.

Comment: I got waves but it shouldn't play.

Comment: You must call `play` method, see updated example - https://jsfiddle.net/n5fmpnyy/2/

Comment: It takes too much time to load.can't load and play some of waves.

Comment: So, example use external files, but this is not my problem, right? My example solve your problem?

Comment: i am getting the error like ReferenceError: wavesurfer is not defined

Comment: Are you kidding me? Include `wavesurfer.js` into page.

Comment: i also include the file on top of the page.

Comment: Then bind `wavesurfer` variable for callback as context - https://jsfiddle.net/n5fmpnyy/3/.

Comment: i want on click play pause

Comment: nothing else you want?

Comment: i take it like onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()" bt it give error like wavesurfer  undefined